# How to send Array list in Jquery with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: c#, jquery, list, xmlhttprequest, webapi

I use XMLHttpRequest to send information and the information I send includes a class in which one of the properties is a list. The problem is that it sends all the information but does not send the desired list.

**Class C#**

```
public class AddProductRequest
{
     public decimal GroupId { get; set; }
     public decimal BrandId { get; set; }
     public List<AdvancedDescription> AdvancedDescriptions { get; set; }
}

public class AdvancedDescription 
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**WebApi Method**

```
[Route("AdminApiAddProduct")]
[HttpPost]
public ResponseBody AdminApiAddProduct(AddProductRequest request)
{
      if ((request.AdvancedDescriptions ?? new List<AdvancedDescription>()).Count > 0)
      {
//Problem Array Count is 0
      }
      var groupId = request.GroupId; //is 12
      var brandId = request.BrandId; //is 13
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$('body').on('click','#bSubmit',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var attributes = 
        [
           {Title : 'test' , Description: 'test'} ,
           {Title: 'test2' , Description : 'test2'}
        ];

   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('request.GroupId', 12);
   formData.append('request.BrandId', 13);
   formData.append('request.AdvancedDescriptions' , attributes);

   var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlHttpRequest.open("POST",
                '@Url.Action("AdminApiAddProduct", "CallApi", new {area = "AdminArea"})',
                true);

   xmlHttpRequest.onloadend = function() {
        var response = JSON.parse(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
   }
   xmlHttpRequest.send(formData);
});
```

The general problem is that the **AdvancedDescription** list is not sent to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, you can use `$.ajax`, construct a JS object and serialize it before sending:

```
$('body').on('click','#bSubmit',function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var attributes = [
    {Title: 'test', Description: 'test'} ,
    {Title: 'test2', Description : 'test2'}
  ];
  
  const data = {
    GroupId: 12,
    BrandId: 13,
    AdvancedDescriptions: attributes
  };
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("AdminApiAddProduct", "CallApi", new {area = "AdminArea"})',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    datatype: 'json',
  })
    .done(function (data) {
      successFunction(data);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      serrorFunction();
    });
});
```

Comment: I updated the anser, let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: did not worked,And it still does not send the list.

Comment: Ok try using JavaScript object rather than FormData, and serialize whole object before sending. Omit "request." literal in keys. Just use plain JS object and serialize it.

Comment: You can give an example with the same data